# Components don't show up after painting

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton, paint

I'm trying to paint a background and then put buttons onto the panel. Without the paint method, the buttons are put correctly onto the screen, but when the paint method is there, the buttons don't show up until the mouse is hovered over them. I can't figure out why this would be. Thanks

this is in the constructor:

```
setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 40, 40, 40));
setSize(1600, 1000);
setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 40, 40));

for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            levels[r][c] = new JButton(String.valueOf(levelNum));
            levels[r][c].setMargin(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
            levels[r][c].addActionListener(e);
            levels[r][c].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            this.add(levels[r][c]);
            levelNum++;
        }
}
```

and then there's:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    ... (just some basic fillRect()'s and things)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't invoke `super.paint(g)` the child components don't get painted.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

However you should NOT be overriding paint() anyway. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method.

The code should be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(...);
    ...
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I'm trying to learn more about using paint, I'll give that a read. Thanks.